# Return from each() not stopping function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking when I user submits a form to check all inputs are filled, but my code carries on even if I return to escape the function.

```
function save(e) {
    $('#storename, #offer').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert("Please fill in all the required fields.");

            return false;
        } 
    });

    //Don't Run Below if inputs are empty..  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a flag to check the validity

```
function save(e) {
    var valid = true;

    $('#storename, #offer').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert("Please fill in all the required fields.");
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }

    });
    if (!valid) {
        return false;
    }

    //Dont Run Bellow if inputs are empty..  

}
```

when you return from the `each` loop, you are only returning from the `each callback` method,  not from the `save` method. You can use a flag to check whether the fields are valid as shown above and use it to return from `save` if needed

Answer (score 1):

```
function save(e) {
       var empty = false;
       $('#storename, #offer').each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() == '') {
             alert("Please fill in all the required fields.");
             empty = true; 
           }

       });
       if(empty) return false;
       //Dont Run Bellow if inputs are empty..  

}
```

You don't actually return any value from `save(e)` function. The only function returning now is the anonymous function inside `each()`.  You need to handle information about empty fields outside the anonymous function like above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but super elegant).

```
function save(e) {
  return !$.grep($('#storename, #offer'), function(el){
               return !$(el).val()}
          ).length;
}
```